# Double values division

Tags: c#, double

i have a problem with a division in c#, i got +infinity and -infity.
I have this code :

```
double Sunrise = 0.0;
double Sunset = 0.0;
double Daylength = 0.0;
Sunrise = 12 - Math.Acos(CosWo) / (15 / 360 * 2 * Math.PI);
Sunset = 12 + Math.Acos(CosWo) / (15 / 360 * 2 * Math.PI);
Daylength = 2 * Math.Acos(CosWo) / (15 / 360 * 2 * Math.PI);
```

When i print the result of sunset sunrise and daylength i got +infinity and -infity for their values, what should i do to fix this.

Comment: Use the debugger ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short story is that `15/360` is returning zero (because of integer division), and then `Math.Acos(CosWo) / 0` will be `+/-Infinity`, depending on the value of `Math.Acos(CosW)`. Changing your code to only use doubles: `15.0 / 360.0 * 2.0 * Math.PI` should fix the issue.

A more detailed explanation:

You'll see `+Infinity/-Infinity` as values for doubles when you divide by zero. Think about it, dividing a number by zero should technically throw an exception, which .NET will for integer division (1/0 will throw a DivideByZeroExeption). For doubles, the IEEE-754 standard (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) defines that when dividing by zero, you'll get `+/-Infinity`. If you think about it, this makes some sense, as dividing by smaller and smaller numbers closer to zero would go to infinity (try 1/0.1, 1/0.001, 1/0.0001, etc. and see for yourself).

Answer (score 3):

You are dividing by an integer value (360) - try doing the following:

```
Sunrise = 12 - Math.Acos(CosWo) / (15 / 360.0 * 2 * Math.PI);
Sunset = 12 + Math.Acos(CosWo) / (15 / 360.0 * 2 * Math.PI);
Daylength = 2 * Math.Acos(CosWo) / (15 / 360.0 * 2 * Math.PI);
```